# Can't find html element's id, name nor class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Want to automate twitter's sending images button so I can send a file with python using selenium with the send_Keys method, but can't find its id or name nor class. This is all the code that appears referent to the button:

[Html twitter send images button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpBi9.png)

Note: None of the classes shown above have worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use x-path, I'm using a chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph?hl=en

To locate the element you want to click.

And then you can use driver.find_element_by_xpath("X-PATH").click()

Comment: Yeah, I did it already and it worked! Thanks. Also, thanks for the chrome extension it would be helpful